# Plot List of Data Frames in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have data frames in a list that corresponds to several variables from a same survey. For example, the dataframe that corresponds to the first variable looks like:

```
Value = c(10, 12, 14, 11)
Quarter = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
dt = as.data.frame(cbind(Quarter, Value))
dt
Value Quarter
 10     1
 12     2
 14     3
 11     4
```

The subsequent follows the same pattern. The plot for a single element of the list was created using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x=Quarter, y=Value))
geom_line()
```

Now, I need to create one plot like above for each element(variable) in my list and save them on my disk. Is it possible to do this using R?

Regards,

Comment: Can you make sure the code you provide actually does what you say it does? For instance, you call `ggplot(...)` and then you call `geom_line()` with no arguments; since they are not connected via a `+`, they are separate expressions and therefore not really doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The most direct way is a `for` loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(your_list)) {
  p = ggplot(data = your_list[[i]], aes(x=Quarter, y=Value)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = paste("Plot", names(your_list)[i])
  ggsave(
    paste0("plot_", i, ".png"),
    plot = p
  )
}
```

You can, of course, customize as much as you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much, Thomas. It worked!